# Create array of paths with spaces in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to define an array of file paths that I can loop over and apply user permissions to. Some of these paths have spaces in them, and the way I'm trying to define the array variable, I cannot loop over them.

```
$rootSitePath = "C:\Path"

$paths = $rootSitePath + "\" + "Path1",
         $rootSitePath + "\" + "Path with spaces",
         $rootSitePath = "\" + "Path3"

foreach($path in $paths)
{
   #do stuff
}
```

Not sure if I need to escape in a certain way??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything special - but you do need to put parenthesis around the array items as you have them above. try:

```
$rootSitePath = "C:\Path"

$paths = ($rootSitePath + "\" + "Path1"),
         ($rootSitePath + "\" + "Path with spaces"),
         ($rootSitePath + "\" + "Path3")

foreach($path in $paths)
{
   get-childitem $path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array `,` operator has higher precedence than the `+` operator for concatentation.

So, if you do something like ( simplified example):

```
$paths = $rootSitePath+"\"+"Path1","path2"
```

`$paths` will be a string because it did string concatentation of `$rootSitePath\` and `Path1 path2` (string representation of the array `"Path1", "path2"`) . So you have to say that the first part before the `,` is the first element:

```
$paths = ($rootSitePath+"\"+"Path1"),"path2"
```

So to solve your problem, enclose each element in parentheses. Apart from that, you are not having problems because your paths had spaces in them.